# Why my caesar cipher is only working in lowercase

Tags: java

I am new in JAVA Programming and I am trying to create a caesar cipher encrypt/decrypt program. Unfortunately, my program is only working in lower cases. I cannot see where did I go wrong I tried reviewing my code for several times but I cant seem to find out the problem. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;                                                                                                         

public class CaesarCipher {                                                                                                       

    public static String encrypt(String plainText, int shift) {                                                                   
        if (shift > 26) {                                                                                                         
            shift = shift % 26;                                                                                                   
        } else if (shift < 0) {                                                                                                   
            shift = (shift % 26) + 26;                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                                         

        String cipherText = "";                                                                                                   
        int length = plainText.length();                                                                                          

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {                                                                                        
            char ch = plainText.charAt(i);                                                                                        

            if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {                                                                                         
                if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {                                                                                  
                    char c = (char) (ch + shift);                                                                                 
                    if (c > 'z') {                                                                                                
                        cipherText += (char) (ch - (26 - shift));                                                                 
                    } else {                                                                                                      
                        cipherText += c;                                                                                          
                    }                                                                                                             
                } else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {                                                                           
                    char c = (char) (ch + shift);                                                                                 
                    if (c > 'Z') {                                                                                                
                        cipherText += (char) (ch - (26 - shift));                                                                 
                    } else {                                                                                                      
                        cipherText += c;                                                                                          
                    }                                                                                                             
                }                                                                                                                 
            } else {                                                                                                              
                cipherText += ch;                                                                                                 
            }                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                         
        return cipherText;                                                                                                        

    }                                                                                                                             

    // Decrypt                                                                                                                    
    public static String decrypt(String plainText, int shift) {                                                                   
        if (shift > 26) {                                                                                                         
            shift = shift % 26;                                                                                                   
        } else if (shift < 0) {                                                                                                   
            shift = (shift % 26) + 26;                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                                         

        String cipherText = "";                                                                                                   
        int length = plainText.length();                                                                                          

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {                                                                                        
            char ch = plainText.charAt(i);                                                                                        

            if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {                                                                                         
                if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {                                                                                  
                    char c = (char) (ch - shift);                                                                                 
                    if (c < 'a') {                                                                                                
                        cipherText += (char) (ch + (26 - shift));                                                                 
                    } else {                                                                                                      
                        cipherText += c;                                                                                          
                    }                                                                                                             
                } else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {                                                                           
                    char c = (char) (ch + shift);                                                                                 
                    if (c < 'A') {                                                                                                
                        cipherText += (char) (ch + (26 - shift));                                                                 
                    } else {                                                                                                      
                        cipherText += c;                                                                                          
                    }                                                                                                             
                }                                                                                                                 
            } else {                                                                                                              
                cipherText += ch;                                                                                                 
            }                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                         
        return cipherText;                                                                                                        

    }                                                                                                                             

    public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                                      
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                                  
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                                  
        System.out.print("Enter your phrase: ");                                                                                  
        String inputPlainText = input1.nextLine();                                                                                
        System.out.print("Enter your shift: ");                                                                                   
        int shiftForPlainText = input1.nextInt();                                                                                 
        String convertPlainText = encrypt(inputPlainText, shiftForPlainText);                                                     
        System.out.println(convertPlainText);                                                                                     

        System.out.print("Enter ciphertext: ");                                                                                   
        String inputCipherText = input2.nextLine();                                                                               
        System.out.print("Enter shift: ");                                                                                        
        int shiftForCipherText = input2.nextInt();                                                                                
        String convertCipherText = decrypt(inputCipherText, shiftForCipherText);                                                  
        System.out.println(convertCipherText);                                                                                    

    }                                                                                                                             
}
```

Comment: Perfect case to learn how to use a debugger!

Answer (score 2):

In `decrypt` method, for lower case you write:

```java
char c = (char)(ch-shift);
```

and for upper case you write:

```java
char c = (char)(ch+shift);
```

I'm pretty sure that both lines should have the same operator between `ch` and `shift`. If you don't want to make such mistakes, try to refactor your code so there are no duplicate lines.